# Update option in admin panel not working - Spring boot - Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, html, json, spring-boot, thymeleaf

While I am trying to update a category name in my e-commerce admin panel, it is not getting updated. And I am getting following error in my terminal:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: The given id must not be null

I am new to spring boot, and I am unable to solve this problem.

My controller methods:

```java
@PostMapping("/add-category")
public String add(@ModelAttribute("categoryNew") Category category, RedirectAttributes attributes) {
try {
categoryService.save(category);

attributes.addFlashAttribute("success", "Added successfully");
} catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
attributes.addFlashAttribute("failed", "Failed to add because duplicate name");
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
attributes.addFlashAttribute("failed", "Error server");
}
return "redirect:/categories";
}

@GetMapping( "/findById")
@ResponseBody
public Category findById(Long id) {

return categoryService.findById(id);
}


@GetMapping("/update-category")
public String update(Category category, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
try {
categoryService.update(category);
redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("success", "Update successfully!");
} catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e1) {
e1.printStackTrace();
redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("error", "Duplicate name of category, please check again!");
} catch (Exception e2) {
e2.printStackTrace();
redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("error", "Error from server or duplicate name of category, please check again!");
}
return "redirect:/categories";
}
```

My Service Implementation:

```java
@Override
public Category save(Category category) {
try {
Category categorySave = new Category(category.getName());
return repo.save(categorySave);
}catch (Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
return null;
}
}

    @Override
    public Category findById(Long id) {

        return repo.findById(id).get();
    }

    @Override
    public Category update(Category category) {
        Category updatedCategory = repo.getById(category.getId());
        updatedCategory.setName(category.getName());
        return updatedCategory;
    }
```

My html with thymeleaf:

```html
    <table class="table table-bordered" th:if="${size>0}">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col"> Category Index</th>
                        <th scope="col">Category Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Edit Category Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr th:each=" category: ${categories}">
                            <th scope="row" th:text="${category.id}"></th>
                            <td  th:text="${category.name}"></td>
                            <td><a id="editButton" th:href="@{/findById(id=${category.id})}" class="btn btn-primary" >Update</a></td>
                            <td>
                                <a th:if = "${category.is_activated()} == true" th:href="@{/delete-category(id=${category.id})}" class="btn btn-warning">Deleted</a>
                                <a th:if = "${category.is_activated()} == false" th:href="@{/enable-category(id=${category.id})}" class="btn btn-primary">Enabled</a>
                            </td>

                        </tr>

                    </tbody>

                </table>

            <!-- End of Main Content -->

            <!-- Footer -->
            <footer th:replace="~{fragments::footer}"></footer>
            <!-- End of Footer -->

        </div>
        <!-- End of Content Wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- End of Page Wrapper -->

    <!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
    <a th:replace="~{fragments:: scroll}"></a>
            <!-- Logout Modal-->

            <!-- Add Modal-->
        <!-- MODAL HERE -->


        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

                <form th:action="@{/add-category}" method="put" th:object="${categoryNew}">

                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New Category</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">

                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Name:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{name}" id="recipient-name">
                                </div>


                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                </form>
            </div>

            <!-- End Modal-->
        <!-- Change Name category Modal-->

        <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="editModalExample" aria-hidden="true">

            <form th:action="@{/update-category}" method="put" th:object="${categoryNew}">

                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="editModalExample">Edit Category</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">

                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="idEdit" class="col-form-label">Id:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="idEdit" name="idEdit" readonly>
                            </div>


                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="nameEdit" class="col-form-label">Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="nameEdit" name="nameEdit">
                            </div>


                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
```

My js file for editbutton:

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
    $('table #editButton').on('click', function (event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $.get(href, function (category, status){
            $('#idEdit').val(category.id);
            $('#nameEdit').val(category.name);
        });
        $('#editModal').modal();
    });
    });
```

Comment: Seems your mappings methods in controller and request methods in your forms varies. Perhaps you can start by unifying them first. eg. `method=put` in the form to match `@PutMapping` in controller